# ¿ Como hago para mostrar el navegador en un panel?

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas querida comunidad tengo problemas para mostrar este link en un  panel, funciona pero se habré un nuevo frame he estado tratando de ponerlo en un panel pero no puedo.

-Como mostrar el navegador en un panel.
-Como hacer para que no navegue por varias paginas y  se quede solo en esta pagina.
-Gracias por tu ayuda.

Este es el método que llamo en mi botón:

private void locate() {

```
    String a = txtMapaBuscador.getText().replace(" ", "+");
   

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1280, 720);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    final JFXPanel fxpanel = new JFXPanel();
    frame.add(fxpanel);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            WebEngine engine;
            WebView wv = new WebView();
            engine = wv.getEngine();
            fxpanel.setScene(new Scene(wv));
            engine.load("https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + a);
        }
    });
}
```